# Writing in second R dataframe column while keeping first column empty

Tags: r

Is there any possibility in R to write second column of dataframe with first column as empty

```
 sampledata <- data.frame()
 sampledata[1:150,2] <- iris$Sepal.Length
```

throwing error like this,

> Error in [<-.data.frame(tmp, 1:75, 2, value = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6,  :
>   new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Comment: Why you are creating an empty data.frame.   why not just `sampledata <- iris$Sepal.Length`

Comment: `sampledata<-data.frame(NA,iris$Sepal.Length)` ? A column can't be empty, at best it can be filled with NA

Comment: sampleData<-data()
  if(!is.null(sampleData[,1]) && ncol(sampleData) == 1){
    isxData = 1
    isyData = 2
    poltare = 1
    #plotType(sampleData[1:length(subx()), 1],suby(),1)
  } else if(!is.null(sampleData[, 2]) && ncol(sampleData) == 3){
    isxData = 2
    isyData = 3
    poltare = 2
    #plotType(sampleData[1:length(subx()),2],sampleData[1:length(suby()),3],2)
  } else if(!is.null(sampleData[, 4]) &&  ncol(sampleData) == 5){
    isxData = 3
    isyData = 4
    poltare = 3

  }
  else if(!is.null(sampleData[, 5]) &&  ncol(sampleData) == 6){
    
  }

Comment: In this second condition fails when first condition doesn't have data

Comment: [edit] your question to add additional details. comments are awful for code and it's unreadable